# Overcurrent LED in LM338 circuit

Tags: current, lm317, over-current

I have an LM338 set up in current regulation mode, and I want to make an LED turn on when the current is maxed out (4A in this case)

[image: LM338 in current regulation mode]

Where do I put this LED, and what other circuitry do I need? Is it even possible? Also an explanation of why I should put it there would be nice so I can learn.

Comment: Does it have to be on the circuit shown? I'm asking this because the easiest way is to put a shunt resistor along the return path and use the voltage drop across it to measure the load current.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Place everything in the blue box below, *before* your regulator IC1:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3bsAK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Q1 switches on when the voltage across sense resistor R1 reaches 0.7V. When it's on, current is able to flow from \$V_{CC}\$ down to ground, via current limiting resistor R3 and LED D1.

Q1 has a few benefits:

1. Reduces the voltage "lost" across sense resistor R1 to 0.7V maximum, keeping drop-out voltage reasonably low.
2. Reduces power dissipation in R1 which would otherwise have to be physically huge, and would dissipate a lot of power.
3. Adds gain, to make the LED switch more emphatically between on and off.
4. Eliminates dependency of R1 upon LED forward voltage.
5. Consistent LED brightness regardless of current, once lit.

Choose R3 in the usual way, to obtain an appropriate current for the LED. For an LED with forward voltage \$V_{LED}\$: $$ R_3 = \frac{V_{CC}-V_{LED}}{I_{LED}} $$

R4 prevents the LED glowing from Q1 leakage current. You may not need it.

The LED may start to glow at around 3.5A but will be fully illuminated at 4A. Change R1 to have the LED switch on at a different current: $$ R_1 = \frac{0.7}{I_{ALARM}} $$

Comment: May I ask, What is R2 for? Is it to limit the current through Q1 so the current doesn’t just flow through the emitter and out the base around R1? How do I calculate a resistance for it?

Comment: @Klumpy7 It's just to limit base current, in case of an output short circuit, which might otherwise cause \$V_{BE}\$ to exceed 0.8V or so.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches. One is to use a general-purpose current sensor circuit, shown below. Q1 amplifies the voltage across Rs and puts it across R2. Q2 compensates Q1's B-E drop. Q3-Q4 are a 0.1mA current source for biasing Q2, also used to generate a reference voltage for the switch Q5. When the  voltage across R2 goes about a diode drop above the reference voltage, Q5 turns on, turning on Q6 and thus the LED.

For higher supply voltages, R5 and R4 should be increased proportionally. For a higher forward-voltage LED, e.g. a blue LED, move the LED above Q6.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4n7cv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The circuit is not very sensitive to supply voltage changes, although the LED intensity will vary with supply voltage. The following plot of LED current vs. load current shows this:

[image]

> I have an LM338 set up in current regulation mode, and I want to make an LED turn on when the current is maxed out

In current regulation, there's either regulation or no regulation, there's no "maxing out" of current. The current may be below the setpoint, when the load impedance is too high, and then the regulator does not regulate anything. Or the current may be at the setpoint - perhaps that's what you mean by "maxed out".

Instead, just say that you want to indicate that the current is being regulated.

Thus the 2nd approach that leverages the architecture of LM338 Darlington output stage. Then current regulation is active, there will be say 2V or more across LM338. That's easy to detect:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f66xvQ.png)</sup>

Q1, Q2 form a differential pair of a comparator. Q3 drives the output LED. D3-D4-RV3 establish the reference voltage. RV3 should be a 200k adjustable, initially set for 100k. RV2 is used to adjust the balance of the differential pair, and also the sharpness of the LED cutoff. After adjusting RV3 for the LED to turn brightly as the input voltage rises and the current gets into regulation, adjust RV2 for the LED to turn off fully when the current is not regulated (under the limit).